# Basic bash behavior

Tags: bash

I expected

```
echo |
```

to do the following:

1. Print the empty string to `stdout`.
2. Pipe `stdout` to `stdin`.

What I would have expected from writing the empty string to `stdin` is: nothing.
What happened instead: A prompt `>` appears which behaves like a bash in the bash:

```
> echo m
m
```

Why is that?

Comment: What are you trying to pipe into?

Comment: The empty string.

Comment: The empty string is not a command: `echo | ''
bash: : command not found`

Comment: The empty command then.

Comment: This command?  http://empty.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Close. But no [cigar](http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Void).

Comment: Another misconception here : `echo` invoked without parameters does not output the empty string but rather `\n`. You'd need `echo -n` to output the empty string.

Comment: the `>` prompt is held in the shell variable `$PS2` -- because of the pipe, bash is waiting for you to complete the command with a valid command. The bash builtin `:` is pretty close to a no-op (when given no arguments).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to pipe into?  The `|` must be followed by another command, and bash shows `>` prompting you to complete the pipeline.

To do both of:

- Print the empty string to stdout.
- Pipe stdout to stdin.

  echo -n '' | cat

Here `cat` is just a placeholder for your second command, which in this case just sends its stdin to its stdout.

Comment: One note, `echo -n` would be sufficient, the empty `''` is unnecessary, just my style to show I intend to print something empty.

Answer (score 6):

`|` is the operator to interconnect two commands.

```
cmd1 | cmd2
```

Starts `cmd1` and `cmd2` in parallel with the stdout of `cmd1` connected to the writing end of a pipe and the stdin of `cmd2` connected to the reading end of that same pipe.

In:

```
cmd1 |
```

You're missing the right-hand command.

The shell tells you that by issuing the secondary prompt (`PS2`, by default `>`) to ask you for the rest of your command.

If you wanted  the stdout of `echo` to be the writing end of a pipe, and its stdin to be the reading end of that same pipe (but note that `echo` doesn't read from its stdin), you'd need to use a shell like `yash` that has an operator for that (the pipeline redirection operator `>>|`):

```
echo test 1>>|0
```

That tells `yash` to create a pipe and assign the writing end to fd 1 (stdout) and the reading end to fd 0 (stdin).

Again, that makes little sense.